# Sin and cos for normal forces on slanted plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, geometry, free-body-diagram

[image]

For a scenario such as this, can someone please explain why $\cos$ is used with the vertical and $\sin$ with the horizontal (with respect to the x-y coordinate system)? I'm used to $\sin$ being related to the $y$ coordinate or vertical direction and $\cos$ to the $x$ coordinate or horizontal direction and don't see what the reasoning is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, sine of an angle for a right triangle is defined as the length of the side opposite the angle divided by the length of the hypotenuse.  The cosine of that same angle is defined as the length of the side adjacent to the angle divided by the length of the hypotenuse.

In your drawing, for the angle shown, the indicated choice of trig functions is correct.  The confusion that you are describing, which arises frequently in the high school physics classes that I teach, is in making the hidden assumption that the cosine of an angle is always the horizontal side of the associated triangle while the sine of the angle is always the vertical side of the associated triangle.  This assumption is just plain false.